# How to retrieve list of object in parse without any duplicity in Xcode?

Tags: xcode5, parse-platform

**Hello every one**
 i want to get my saved data from parse.com one time for every duplicated row, as it's shown in the bellow

```
 Name       Country
------     --------
Person#1    Albania
Person#2    Bulgaria
Person#3    China
Person#4    Albania
Person#5    China
Person#6    Finland
Person#7    China
```

and i want to get this result, if it is possible

```
Country
-------
Albania
Bulgaria
China
Finland
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a query on the class then use fast enumeration to add the objects to an NSSet after checking that it does NOT exist in the set. NSSet can only contain unique objects and they are fast at checking if a certain object is in a set. Assuming that your parse class is called Person and the country property is called country, you can try the following:

In the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableSet *uniqueCountries;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *countryToCheck;
```

In the .m file:

```
 _uniqueCountries = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];

    PFQuery *personQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Person"];

    [personQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        for (PFObject *person in objects){

            _countryToCheck = [person objectForKey:@"country"];

            if (![_uniqueCountries containsObject:_countryToCheck]) {

                [_uniqueCountries addObject:_countryToCheck];
            }


        }

        //Log out the set. It should only contain unique countries
        NSLog(@"%@",_uniqueCountries);
    }];
```

Hope it helps